# Desktop LCD monitor which allows backlight to be controlled in software

Tags: desktop, lcd, backlight

I would like to know if there is any standard or feature which allows desktop LCD monitors backlight control setting in software. I would like to know what I should be searching for. This is a pretty common feature of laptop computers, but I'm not able to find an equivilant for desktop/standalone monitors.

I have tried a few 'sofware only' solutions which effectively just control the brightness sent to the monitor - not the backlight of the monitor itself.

Of course I can change the setting easily by using the OSD of any monitor but this is not always convienient to change.

Comment: I think I've answered my own question - the standard is DDC/CI and seems to be widely supported. Software is available from http://ddc-ci.com

Comment: That’s the answer indeed, so make it one. ;) Answering your own question is possible and encouraged.

Comment: @DanielB This question was 'on-hold' at the time I wrote the comment

Comment: Also, see this question http://superuser.com/questions/187302/how-to-adjust-monitors-backlight-brightness-in-windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard is DDC/CI and seems to be widely supported - it may need to be enabled from the monitors OSD (mine was disabled).

softMCCS from ddc-ci.com allows lots of control but it's too low level technical for regular use.

Just to control brightness and contrast I'm using http://clickmonitorddc.bplaced.net (Windows).

Comment: The link to clickmonitorddc no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

Try either [TwinkleTray](https://github.com/xanderfrangos/twinkle-tray) (it works for me on Win10 2020) or [Monitorian](https://github.com/emoacht/Monitorian).

ClickMonitorDDC seems to be down/no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

DDC/CI is a quite simple standard that already exists for a long time. However, monitors vary wildly in support and correctness weirdly enough. Microsoft also never bothered to have a 'designed for Windows' certificate or something which could have easily fixed the lazy support from manufacturers. One compact utility to try is https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ws-monitor-controls/9mzx4mf014qk
Let's you adjust brightness, contrast, colour and volume (all depending on monitor willingness to cooporate).